# Laravel 4 pretty urls

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, vhosts

Ok I was working on a project using laravel 4. I never bothered setting up vhosts for pretty urls. I was just using localhost/myapp/public...

Everything was working fine. Now I have decided to set up vhosts. And I'm getting the following error when `$user->save();` is called:

```
ReflectionException
Class confide.repository does not exist.
```

Auto-loading is not working why??

What am I forgetting??

Here is my vhost.conf set up:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.6>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\public"
    ServerName myapp.dev
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And my hosts setup:

```
127.0.0.6 myapp.dev
```

UPDATE: when I configure vhosts with: `ServerName myapp` instead of `ServerName myapp.dev`
It works great, however I want the .dev so that that I can use facebooks api.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to dump the autoload: `composet dump-autoload` that shouldn' t be the problem, but give it a try.

Comment: Thank Christian I tried it several times no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're on a Windows machine.

### VHosts (Windows) related:

I'm using vhosts myself. Here's a copy of what I'm using in my WAMP Environment:

```
# Virtual Hosts Settings
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName appdomain.local
  DocumentRoot "D:/Program Files/wamp/www/appname"
  ErrorLog "D:/Program Files/wamp/www/appname/server_logs/errors.log"
  TransferLog "D:/Program Files/wamp/www/appname/server_logs/access.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

…and in the hosts file I use:

```
127.0.0.1    appdomain.local
```

Try these settings and see if it works.

*BTW.: Why are you using 127.0.0.6? Localhost is equal to 127.0.0.1... To use another IP some other settings need to be set / adjusted in Windows.*

### Laravel 4 related:

Have you checked the User model and composer.json file?

Did you follow the necessary installation instructions on https://github.com/Zizaco/confide#quick-start ?

Double check that.

Also look at this: https://github.com/Zizaco/confide/issues/9

#### About my App/Config/app.php config file:

I've setup a "production" and "local" app config. The main differences for the local version are:

```
 - debug  =>  true                   (production => false)
 - url    =>  THE_APP_LOCAL_DOMAIN   (production => THE_APP_DOMAIN)
```

Everything else is set in the production config.

**Providers example:**

```
'providers' => array(
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
    ...,
),
```

**Aliases example:**

```
'aliases' => array(
    'App'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
    'Carbon' => 'Carbon\Carbon',
    ...,
),
```

I always update the autoload *(> composer dump-autoload)* on:

- namespace changes
- composer.json edits
- composer updates (e.g. after adding a new package from like packagist)
- and config changes, just to be save

---

**Also try the following commands:** (don't forget to *cd* to the project directory first)

- composer dump-autoload
- php artisan dump-autoload
- php artisan cache:clear

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried all the following commands, but still no success. I also tried your exact setup same same errors. The reason I'm using 127.0.0.6 is that I have older projects on the other IPs. Everything works find when I access the site as follows: localhost/myapp/public I just don't understand why vhosts is causing such a major problem, its driving me mad.

Comment: I've setup the "production" and "local" versions of the app/config/app.php files, e.g. 'debug' => false in production and true in /local/app.php . I'll update my answer with some insight in my config setup for you.

Comment: @user1543871 BTW: according to your first comment it sounds like there's some issue with relative and absolute project paths. Did you check that out yet?